# cocos2dx Sprite setPosition error

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I am positioning an image sprite at location *(0,0)* so that left edge of screen co incides with left edge of image. But the image always appears at the center of the screen, with both the image and screen's center coinciding.

The size of the `CCImage` is 854 x 480 and `getVisibleSize()` returns 320 x 240.
To display the sprite with the image's left coinciding with the screen's left edge I have to `setPosition` at x= -264

I have gone through this wiki at [cocos2dx wiki co-ordinates systems](http://devcircle.blogspot.in/2013/03/cocos2d-x-coordinate-system.html) which says that *(0,0)* starts at left bottom.
I have also seen [Cocos2d-x reference of setPosition method](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/d0/ded/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_node.html#a043d491dc14639ca380dbf0b7812ad47) which iterates the same.

Am I missing something? Any ideas why this may be happening?

**UPDATE**
I think I should mention that I am using the `CCLayerPanZoom` extension for this.
`getAnchorPoint()` returns x = 0.5 and y = 0.5

Comment: Did you modify anchorPoint of the image and any of its parents? Also keep in mind that positions are offsets to the parent's (and the parent's parent and so on) positions, so if one of the parent's position is 264,0 then all of the children will be offset by the same amount.

Comment: anchorPoint is (0.5 , 0.5)

Comment: I agree. The parent of the sprite might not be at 0,0

Answer (score 0):

This will position your image sprite to left bottom of screen:

```
sprite->setAnchorPoint(CCPoint(0, 0));

sprite->setPosition( ccp(0,0));
```